# VS 2015 license has been expired

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I downloaded VS 2015 enterprise (release edition) from my MSDN account yesterday (July 21, 2015) and installed it on a brand new W8.1 pro machine (Yes. Sadly, I can't upgrade Win8.1 Pro to Enterprise. https://superuser.com/questions/943202/upgrading-windows-8-1-retail-to-windows-8-1-enterprise-msdn?noredirect=1#comment1283892_943202 )

After I signed in with my MSDN account in VS 2015, I got the error saying that **this license has expired**.  How is it possible? Is it the known issue? Is there any way to fix it? Thanks!

Update: I have VS 2015 beta/CTP version that I was testing in my old laptop and desktop machine. But the error that I have is on my new laptop. I guess my old prerelease license and new release version license might got mixed up.

Comment: I'm not sure if you realize but your email address is visible here. You might want to delete the photo.

Comment: VS 2015 has just been officially released, so the expiration of a prerelease install might be related to that (though I would have guessed they would allow some overlap period).

Comment: Thanks @Mehrdad... I used to have VS 2015 pre-release installed in another machine. But I downloaded the release version yesterday and installed it on new fresh machine.

Comment: I get a similar issue with VS 2015 community issue - it says the prerelease license has expired and exits afters displaying that dialog. Since this is the first time I've installed any VS2015, I won't have any other license other than for VS 2013 Community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve the problems.

Initially, I logged in with my orgid in IE so I logged out and logged in again with my Microsoft Account.

I run VS 2015 to repair the VS again.

After that, I found it working fine now.

Hope it helps if someone else have the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sign out from your account, restart Visual Studio 2015 then again sign in to same account, it will keep extending your trial period.

Comment: This worked for me.  I had even tried uninstalling and reinstalling and it still remembered the old trial account.  Wish I had this trick this before wiping all of my TFS setup.