# How to change Visual Studio 2017 License Key?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, license-key

I want to remove my license key in visual studio 2017.
how can i do it?
I am trying to change the product key but I cant.

Answer (score 53):

Well I found two possible solutions for **Visual Studio 2013, 2015, 2017, 2019** and **2022**.

**1. Setting new product key with `StorePID.exe` ([MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/automatically-apply-product-keys-when-deploying-visual-studio)).**

1. navigate to VS 2017/2019 installation directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE`)
2. start `cmd` as admin
3. execute `StorePID.exe <your_new_product_key> <MPC>`
4. maybe a restart

Possible Microsoft Product Codes (MPC) are:

- `06177` Visual Studio *Professional* 2013
- `06191` Visual Studio *Premium* 2013
- `06181` Visual Studio *Ultimate* 2013
- `07062` Visual Studio *Professional* 2015
- `07060` Visual Studio *Enterprise* 2015
- `08860` Visual Studio *Enterprise* 2017
- `08862` Visual Studio *Professional* 2017
- `08866` Visual Studio *Test Professional* 2017
- `09260` Visual Studio *Enterprise* 2019
- `09262` Visual Studio *Professional* 2019
- `09660` Visual Studio *Enterprise* 2022
- `09662` Visual Studio *Professional* 2022

**2. Removing product key first and set new one. *(VS 2015/2017/2019)***

1. open register editor
2. navigate to

- VS 2015: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\4D8CFBCB-2F6A-4AD2-BABF-10E28F6F2C8F` and delete it
- VS 2017: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\5C505A59-E312-4B89-9508-E162F8150517` and delete it
- VS 2019: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\41717607-F34E-432C-A138-A3CFD7E25CDA` and delete it

3. exeute a repair installation of VS 2017/2019
4. enter your new product key under Help > Register Product

It's not the best way to solve it, but faster than deinstall and install the complete IDE.

---

#### Update (2020-01-09)

- added MPCs for Visual Studio 2013, 2015 and 2019;
- extended registry solution for VS 2019;

#### Update (2021-12-03)

- added MPCs for Visual Studio 2022;

Comment: I wanted to remove a product key to enable my VisualStudio.com subscription benefit. If you want to accomplish this, both procedures work. 
Procedure 1 can be used with any properly formatted product key; it does not have to be a valid one. 
Procedure 2 can be used without the (rather invasive) repair option. Instead, just execute a Modify action without actually changing anything. This will have the same result in regards to the product key without the hassle of removing user settings and the long wait.

Comment: Slight correction: Procedure 1 seems to (silently) return an error (5). I don't know why this is, but since Procedure 2 works fine I'm tempted to stick with that.

Comment: Okay, 1 works for me without any (silent) errors. :/

Comment: how did you find out these GUIDs? I wanted to check for VS2022...

Answer (score 7):

For VS 2019 the registry key is: 
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\41717607-F34E-432C-A138-A3CFD7E25CDA`

Answer (score 5):

For VS 2015, a key is

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\4D8CFBCB-2F6A-4AD2-BABF-10E28F6F2C8F
```

for what it's worth...

Comment: How did you come up with this? How would I find this out for other products?
(e.g. VS 2019)

Answer (score 5):

can't write comments so I give you this in the form of an answer, hoping @ChW will incorporate it in his winning answer:

Removing product key first and set new one. (VS 2022)

1. open registry editor
2. navigate to

   VS 2022: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\1299B4B9-DFCC-476D-98F0-F65A2B46C96D and delete it
3. execute a repair installation of VS 2022
4. enter your new product key under Help > Register Product

Answer (score 2):

MPCs for VS 2019.

Visual Studio Enterprise 2019   09260

Visual Studio Professional 2019 09262

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/automatically-apply-product-keys-when-deploying-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1):

MPCs for VS 2022

Visual Studio Enterprise 2022     09660

Visual Studio Professional 2022   09662

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/automatically-apply-product-keys-when-deploying-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).