# Extract visual studio 2017 product key

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 Professional with a product key.
Now I would like to install VS 2017 Professional on a different machine. How can I retrieve the product key used in the first installation?

I googled and found VS no longer stores keys directly in the registry. Instead, there's a new way to extract the key. I followed the links below:

- [How to change Visual Studio 2017 license key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731291/how-to-change-visual-studio-2017-license-key)
- [Updating registry settings for Visual Studio 2017](https://blog.agchapman.com/updating-registry-settings-for-visual-studio-2017/)

However, I could not find the exact location where the product key is stored.

Answer (score 2):

You can find MS VS 2017 product key information from: https://my.visualstudio.com/productkeys

Comment: getting There is no paid active subscription associated with your account.nothing showing up

Comment: same issue.. hopefully someone has the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this in
[Retrieve Visual Studio 2017 (Enterprise) Key from privateregistry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577239/retrieve-visual-studio-2017-enterprise-key-from-privateregistry)
. Note that you will need to change the registry path to end with `2` (Professional) instead of `0` (Enterprise).