# Retrieve Visual Studio 2017 (Enterprise) Key from privateregistry

Tags: visual-studio-2017, product-key

I have bought a new SSD and want to reinstall Windows 10 and Visual Studio Enterprise 2017. The problem is, I got an "On the Hub" Account as a Student, on which you can get Microsoft Products for free, but now it seems that my Account has been removed since I left school a while ago, but my Keys still work (VS and as well Windows 10).

I did retrieve my Windows 10 Key from registry but since VS 2017 doesn’t store Keys in registry but in the privateregistry.bin file, i can’t seem to find the Key itself. The closest I got is adding the hive file in Regedit and looking into it.

[image: RegEdit showing privateregistry]
But in the Registration, as well in the Licences folder are no real Keys saved.

Is there a possibility to retrieve it from somewhere in the hive or maybe can i just copy the privateregistry.bin file and add it into the Appdata folder after formatting? I didn’t wanted to format before I’m sure, so I don’t lose my license.

Comment: You can still login to "on the hub" and go to the Orders tab to find the CdKey there

Comment: I cant login "on the hub" anymore, i tried to retrieve my Password but it says that the email isnt registered on their site, when clearly the orders are in my email archieve, unfortunately there is no Key listed. Thats why i think my account got deleted.

Comment: I found an old text file containing the key so I tried it. I tried to copy the privateregistry file and also the full folder for Visual Studio Configuration, both didnt unfortunately work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be able to find the activation key under the registry path `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\5C505A59-E312-4B89-9508-E162F8150517\08860` . The value is encrypted though, so you need to decrypt it with the `CryptUnprotectData` method in the Win32 API.

I have created a small tool that simplifies this and should allow extracting product keys for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 (only tested for 2019 professional so far):

https://github.com/terjew/VSKeyExtractor

Comment: I tried it out with VS 2019 and it did extract the Key, thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly here on VS2017, thanks. Had to retarget to .NET 4.8 and get rid of the 'record' syntax to build it, but that was it.

Comment: Found a VS2017 key that I didn't know I had. Thank you!

Comment: Works with VS2022, too. Thank you. :)

Comment: Life Saver - thanks