# Is possible to retrieve VS 2017 Product Key?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, product-key

I got my VS 2017 product key from my University Program, now Microsoft changed the site and I can't retrieve anymore my old product keys, but actually VS 2017 has a valid product key. I want to store it so I'm looking a way to retrieve this from my licensed VS 2017.
I found that VS 2017 doesn't store product key in registry anymore, so there is another way to find it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found info on extracting the plaintext product key, but it's still stored in the registry, just in an encoded format. See [How to change Visual Studio 2017 License Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731291/how-to-change-visual-studio-2017-license-key). You might be able to export/import the relevant registry key to your new computer.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this in [Retrieve Visual Studio 2017 (Enterprise) Key from privateregistry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577239/retrieve-visual-studio-2017-enterprise-key-from-privateregistry)

Depending on which version you have, you might have to change the last digit of the registry key.