# Upgrading from visual studio 2017 community to Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2017, upgrade, license-key

I have been using the Community edition of Visual studio 2017 but now my office has purchased a Visual Studio 2017 Pro License key.

Is there a way in which I can upgrade using just the license key..?? without re-installing the software..?

I have tried following the steps in this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-unlock-visual-studio#to-unlock-visual-studio-with-a-product-key)

But I cant find the

> License with a Product Key
>    link.
>   NOTE: I have already signed in with my Microsoft account.

I have read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46974337/2010194)

But it looks like the guy has already installed 2017 enterprise edition and then changed his license key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We cannot upgrade VS 2017 from community to the Professional version, but we can keep those VS versions (community/professional/enterprise) on the same computer which is different with the previous VS versions, so you can download and install the VS professional 2017 without uninstall the existing VS community 2017.

BTW, the VS community 2017 is free and we can unlock it through sign in with the Microsoft account, but there have the license terms to check we have the freely use right or not, please check [this](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt553321/) and if not meet those requirements, please uninstall it.

Comment: I have completely uninstalled the Visual Studio 2017 and then installed the Visual Studio 2017 Pro edition and applied the Pro License. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this same concern at my job.  My Visual Studio subscription was not available right away, but I wanted to start looking at code, so I installed Visual Studio 2022 Community.

Later, when I had access to my subscription, I removed Community using Visual Studio Installer and choosing More -> Uninstall.  After that I logged on to the subscriber portal and downloaded and installed Professional.

Everything is working like normal now.