# Visual Studio 2017 - Prerelease software. This license has expired

Tags: visual-studio-2017

**Issue:** Download Visual Studio Community 2017

And the login dialog says, **"Prerelease software. This license has expired"** even though I'm logged in with a valid account. My laptop and another PC are both running the same version linked to the same account. They work fine.

I've tried everything outlined here (#answer-47683843):
[Visual Studio 2015 - Prerelease software. This license has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725192/visual-studio-2015-prerelease-software-this-license-has-expired/#answer-47683843)

Comment: I had the same error with VS 2019 Community edition and just switched to using VS Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by **resetting my Windows 10 OS** (https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/reset-windows-10-pc), which is kind of annoying - **but it worked!**

Here's my [visual studio support ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/162921/visual-studio-2017-error-after-install-prerelease.html) in case they ever decide to fix the issue without such an extreme approach.

***Coming from a guy that spent hours*** reinstalling VS over and over and OVER again... And trying to come up with all kinds of workarounds with VMs and deleting registry keys, etc...

**This was a way better sure-fire, fairly quick, fix compared to all that!**

I've never reset my Windows 10 before this, and so far **it's really not too intrusive.** All my data is still on the machine, you can choose JUST to clean out your apps, and Windows settings (which I assume includes your registry).

So I'll be reinstalling a bunch of stuff... but again... **it was way worth it, if you need Visual Studio 2017 *working now***

Hope this helps someone else out there!