# Visual Studio 2015 (License: This license has expired)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I downloaded Visual Studio 2015 Community, I installed the program and after clicking LAUNCH, it says that the license has expired with on top of it license: `Prerelease software.`

I can't click anything other than that just signing in which doesn't help either.

I tried everything:

1. repairing (control panel > programs > programs and features).
2. uninstalling Visual Studio and reinstalling.
3. deleting all the trace of the program via revouninstaller and reinstalling it again.
4. downloading the iso. file and installing it from my drive.
5. unpacking the iso. file then installing it again.
6. waiting for a miracle and trying to reinstalling it 10 times more.
7. trying to search for a solution on the internet.

All the things that i tried didn't work, i just got stuck on the "sign in to visual studio" page.

If I click close, the entire program just closes off.

**I know there a similar questions to this, but nothing worked for me.**

I really want this to be solved, I just got really tired, installing this program over and over again.

So I hope that someone might help me.

ps: I upgraded from windows 7 to windows 10 about a month ago.

pps: English is not my native language so I hope you understand what my problem is regarding this issue.

ppps: This is my first time asking a question on the internet, if I didn't clearify something about my problem then i apologize.

Comment: register your visual studio

Comment: same issue over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725192/visual-studio-2015-prerelease-software-this-license-has-expired and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551574/vs-2015-license-has-been-expired and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537812/license-expired-after-installation-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-community and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252068/visual-studio-2015-rc-community-says-this-license-has-expired

Comment: i know that there are similar questions, and i have read them all. but nothing seems to work, that's why i ask this question (knowing that this question exist here) to find a solution about this issue. EuphoriaGrogi, How do i register my product? i really don't know how to do that, even though i searched for it.

Comment: you need to login to your visual studio (Help-->About--->Product license information) if you have a microsoft account, if not then you can make one under the same panel that is open.

Comment: Where did you download it from?

Comment: i already have a visual studio account and a microsoft account. The problem is i always got stuck at the sign in page, with the message this license has expired, i just downloaded visual studio express 2015 windows 10, still the same issue. but now there is a new option "check for an updated license" when clicked there is this message shown "downloaded license is insufficient".

Comment: i downloaded it from https://www.visualstudio.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Someone reported a similar problem for the Team Foundation Server [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2015/08/06/team-foundation-server-2015-final-release.aspx). This was his workaround:

> 1. Uninstall if you have it installed.
> 2. Mount the ISO and get the versions for the 4 C++ runtimes (2 are 32-bit and 2 are 64-bit). Uninstall all of these.
> 3. From the ISO, run all 4 of the C++ runtime installers as administrator
> 4. From the ISO, run the main TFS installer as administrator

Maybe the same works for your Visual Studio installation?

Note that the Visual Studio ISO contains 3 versions of the C++ runtime (11, 12 and 14), so you should try to reinstall all 6 of those.

Comment: i followed the solution that you give me, but it didn't solve the issue :( anyway, thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with VS 2015 Pro:

[Ultimate 2015 CTP License Expiration](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1105774/ultimate-2015-ctp-license-expiration)

In short, the license error could happen if you are installing from a path which contains spaces.